# How to put $$ around numbers in R?

Tags: r

**How can I put the arrays of a matrix in double $$ in R?**

Comment: This is very vague. Give an example of your input data, and exactly what you want the output to look like. I'm guessing that you are looking to embed some results from R into TeX; if so, there are packages that aid with that (`xtable` among them). Finally, once this question is more fleshed out, it will likely belong on stackoverflow rather than Cross Validated because it is a question on programming, not statistical concepts.

Comment: Exactly, you are right. I also used 'xtable'. Because I use a Persian font in LaTeX, I need to put all of output numbers in $$. I want to know is there any way that I do this in R? I tried 'as.charcter' but xtable doesn't work for it.

Comment: Alas, this question is off topic here.  It *might* be on topic on SO, but you need to improve the question before they will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I imagine that you want this is in order to export this into LaTeX.  In which case, I encourage you to read into SWeave (or knitr), and also have a look at the xtable package.